# Why am I getting repeated "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" errors, solved just by deleting node_modules?

Tags: angular, angular8

I develop a product that is already in production. Angular 8 with NodeJs backend.

For some time I'm repeatedly getting this error some times a day:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at registerNgModuleType (vendor.js:67133:34)
    at vendor.js:67144:47
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (vendor.js:67144:17)
    at new NgModuleFactory (vendor.js:67251:13)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (vendor.js:70711:25)
    at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (vendor.js:70921:16)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.js:11665:100)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85:30)
    at Object.0 (main.js:11678:18)
```

When I get it, I just delete node_modules, install modules again and it works fine. The problem is that as the system is relatively big at this point I loose a lot of time reinstalling modules again and again.

It's not a matter of something being loaded in some module, because it doesn't matter which module I enter (even about module that doesn't load anything) I get the error.

I know I'm not providing a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example", but I don't know how I can provide a normal code example, because it's a system-wide problem.

I'm making this question hoping someone has seen something like this and can give me a clue of what's corrupting node_modules.

Some time ago this didn't happen. Now it's seem to be getting worse, like happening several times a day.

Why does this occur ? Or what I can put in a question that can be verifiable given the case ?

**Edit**

This is the code in main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

console.log('Build:', environment.build);
if (environment.type == 'production') {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**Edit 2**

OK.. nothing resists brute force. What I did was copying the whole project folder, them I removed all system modules, one by one until there was only About page left. Even then the error was still there. So I started deleting app.modules dependencies one by one. When I deleted nearly all them it finally worked.
Then I reactivated all other modules and commented the one that I knew caused the error. The error returned. So I go on, one by one until I identified all modules that was causing the error.
Here are them:

```
    imports: [
//      NgxSpinnerModule, 
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
//      NgSelectModule, 
        FormsModule,
//      ModalModule.forRoot(), 
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
//      FileUploadModule, 
//      CarouselModule.forRoot(), 
//      TypeaheadModule.forRoot(), 
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
//      NgDatepickerModule, 
//      IMaskModule, 
//      NgxFilesizeModule, 
        SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
//      NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),  
//      ColorPickerModule 
    ],
```

If I uncomment anyone of the commented lines the error returns.
OK... one step ahead. But I lost the funcionality of these modules that I really need. AFAI imagine at the moment, I must be some conflict between an Angular lib and these modules.

Comment: In your code in template of component you may be need to access id property like this `data?.id` so that when data is undefined then you can not get this I'd error. And it's in line main.js:11665:100 as you have shred it

Comment: I shared Main.ts code in the question. There's no .id there. Can it be app.module ? if it can the problem can be in any system module. And why would it fix after removing node_modules ? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not about main.ts, it's about at somewhere in your code you are accessing I'd property of undefined object.

Comment: That's what I thought. I searched by all occurences of .id. Removed one by one. Nothing. And that doesn't explain why it works after I delete node_modules.

Comment: May be it works after deleting node_module, cause it resets all state of objects. May be at run time sometimes you get undefined object and access id property of it and the same object you get values then it works perfectly. So deleting modules resets your states of project. Or may be any third party package you install as dependency causes this, but to use angular 8 is not recommended now cause current version is 13 and you should keep up to date angular version.

Comment: I'm afraid that's exactly the point. Old version from Angular causing problems with dependencies. What I'm doing right now is deleting every module of the system one by one, leaving only About page. Of course I did a backup before I did this. Let's see if I can pinpoint where it's coming from.

Comment: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/read-your-production-angular-errors-like-a-pro-32c3df34bdae this link may be helpful to you

Comment: Please see my Edit 2

Comment: Just double check all commented modules are compatible with angular version 8. Means all dependency must have angular 8 running.